# Unwrap optional text from JSON

Tags: json, swift, string, option-type, unwrap

I have multiple strings returned from JSON and tried various options, but couldn't unwrap the optional content in it. Code snippet below

```
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!,options: .allowFragments)    
as! [String:Any]

let currentConditions = parsedData["Result"] as! [String:Any]

self.fname = (currentConditions["fname"] as! String)
self.lname = (currentConditions["lname"] as! String)

print(self.fname!)
print(self.lname!)
```

On printing self.fname and self.lname always it returns the values as

```
Optional("("firstName")")
Optional("Optional("lastName")"
```

I have tried various options tried in stackoverflow like using

```
if let fname = fname {
    let ui1 = String(fname)
    print(fname)
}
```

and unwrapping it using !. Nothing worked.Kindly help.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply giving the print() a default value?

```
print(self.fname ?? "")
```

Btw, I think the problem is that these are double optionals. You need to unwrap them twice.

```
// If you just want to bang these out.
print((self.lname!)!).
```

Answer (score 0):

*Unwrap like this!*

```
guard let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!,options: .allowFragments)
            as? [String:Any] else { return }
        
guard let currentConditions = parsedData["Result"] as? [String:Any] else { return }

guard let fname = currentConditions["fname"] as? String, let lname = currentConditions["lname"] as? String else { return }


print(fname) //firstName
print(lname) //lastName
```